# Internet connection not shared with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, share

I have been following the same tuto as this one [Sharing the Pi's WiFi connection through the Ethernet port](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48307/sharing-the-pis-wifi-connection-through-the-ethernet-port/59137#59137).

I have a very similar setup. My phone hotspot providing the internet. My Pi connects with wlan0 to this hotspot, and shares it through eth0 (connected to a switch to share it with any connected device).

After following the previously mentioned tutorial, I managed to have:

- Internet on my Pi
- an IP attributed by the Pi to any connected devices to the switch.

However, those connected devices do not have the Internet. Any idea how to debug/what to check? 
I run line by line the script "bridge.sh", and everything was successful.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Wishes,
Arnaud