# 'dnsmasq' starting error

Tags: networking, dhcp, dns

I need to configure wifi-eathernet bridge for my IP cameras net. I've tried to use this tutorial: [Sharing the Pi's WiFi connection through the Ethernet port](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48307/sharing-the-pis-wifi-connection-through-the-ethernet-port/50073#50073?newreg=47668a02535f4e57be8a953f5790620a), to resolve my issue and experienced another one. When I try to start dnsmasq as **sudo systemctl start dnsmsq** the error occured. Here is the code:

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
         └─50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
Active: failed (Result: resources) since Tue 2018-06-12 14:01:24 UTC; 44s ago
Process: 1072 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1069 ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1067 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1064 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Also, here is **sudo journalctl -u dnsmasq.service** result:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-06-12 14:01:03 UTC, end at Tue 2018-06-12 14:41:02 UTC. --
Jun 12 14:01:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jun 12 14:01:07 raspberrypi dnsmasq[445]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jun 12 14:01:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post.
Jun 12 14:01:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jun 12 14:01:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit dnsmasq.service entered failed state.
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1064]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post.
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jun 12 14:01:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit dnsmasq.service entered failed state.
```

**Result: resources** - not a very informative message. Could you please help me with this.

Here are all configuration:

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=eth0
listen-address=172.24.2.1
bind-interfaces                         
server=8.8.8.8                          
domain-needed                           
bogus-priv                              
dhcp-range=172.24.2.50,172.24.2.60,12h
```

**/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Jun 12 11:45:00 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 12 11:45:00 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Jun 12 11:45:00 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 12 11:45:00 2018
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotlug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.24.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.24.2.0
    broadcast 172.24.2.255


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward**

```
1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything useful from `journalctl -u dnsmasq.service`? If so, it might be helpful to [edit] the output into your post.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Unfortunately:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -u dnsmasq.service
No journal files were found.

Comment: Oh, you might need to run it with root (`sudo journalctl -u dnsmasq.service`); apparently that's systemd's way of telling you that you haven't got privileges!

Comment: Yeeeah, you are right. My bad.