# Forward internet to usb0

Tags: raspbian, gadget

I have Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian) and Raspberry Pi Zero (DietPi). The Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to ethernet. The Raspberry Pi Zero is set as Ethernet gadget (according to this https://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1589&p=6639#p6639) and connected to the RPi3 via USB.

The Raspberry Pi 3 detects it as usb0. I've set static IP using the GUI.[image]

The image: 
`ifconfig` from RPi3:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.46  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
        inet6 fe80::dc28:3374:b490:2a12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:77:af:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13924  bytes 937061 (915.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 223  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2621  bytes 1384168 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::8e2e:c0ad:d6f1:e985  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:5f:b5:24:dc:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 126  bytes 14905 (14.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 365  bytes 95162 (92.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ip a` from RPi0:

```
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:31:20:c9:dc:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.2/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global usb0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::31:20ff:fec9:dcbd/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How do I forward the internet from RPi3 to the RPi0? I've tried the script (edited to match my options) from: [Sharing the Pi's WiFi connection through the Ethernet port](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48307/sharing-the-pis-wifi-connection-through-the-ethernet-port)

But that didn't work. `ping google.com` resulted in `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`. I've tried adding dns to the `resolv.conf` on the Pi0, but also didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice picture, but cannot read it. Is it important for your question? If so, please paste it as text into the question.

Comment: Please add the output from `ip route` to your question.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Share-WiFi-With-Ethernet-Port-on-a-Raspberry-Pi/ I use this guide and a similar one just search google tbf, change the wlan0 with your input internet and change their eth0 to your output internet to the pi you are forwarding on don't bother with the wi fi user / pass unless doing wifi